# #90: Error inflating class ImageButton

Tags: android, android-fragments, nononsense-filepicker

I am using [NoNonsense-FilePicker](https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker) for filtering the sd card for pdf files by extending the FilePickerActivity and creating a [FilteredFilePickerFragment](http://spacecowboy.github.io/NoNonsense-FilePicker/example/filter_file_extension/) instance through it but i get an error related to an Image button in it's resources.

this is the File Picker Fragment Extender:

```
public class FilePickerFragmentExtender extends FilePickerActivity {

public FilePickerFragmentExtender() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected AbstractFilePickerFragment<File> getFragment(@Nullable String startPath, int mode, boolean allowMultiple, boolean allowCreateDir, boolean allowExistingFile, boolean singleClick) {
    AbstractFilePickerFragment<File> fragment = new FilteredFilePickerFragment();
    // startPath is allowed to be null. In that case, default folder should be SD-card and not "/"
    fragment.setArgs(startPath != null ? startPath : Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(),
            mode, allowMultiple, allowCreateDir, allowExistingFile, singleClick);
    return fragment;
  }
}
```

and this is the Filtered File Picker Fragment:

```
public class FilteredFilePickerFragment extends FilePickerFragment {
private static final String TAG = "FilteredFilePickerFragm";
// File extension to filter on
private static final String EXTENSION = ".pdf";

public FilteredFilePickerFragment() {
    super();
}

/**
 * @param file
 * @return The file extension. If file has no extension, it returns null.
 */
private String getExtension(@NonNull File file) {
    String path = file.getPath();
    int i = path.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (i < 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return path.substring(i);
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean isItemVisible(final File file) {
    boolean ret = super.isItemVisible(file);
    if (ret && !isDir(file) && (mode == MODE_FILE || mode == MODE_FILE_AND_DIR)) {
        String ext = getExtension(file);
        return ext != null && EXTENSION.equalsIgnoreCase(ext);
    }
    return ret;
  }
}
```

the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                  Process: com.pdfviewer.debug, PID: 15693
                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pdfviewer.debug/com.pdfviewer.FilePickerFragmentExtender}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #90: Binary XML file line #90: Error inflating class ImageButton
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496)
                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #90: Binary XML file line #90: Error inflating class ImageButton
                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #90: Error inflating class ImageButton
                                                   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010031 a=-1}
                                                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:528)
                                                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:180)
                                                      at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:84)
                                                      at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:80)
                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:60)
                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:56)
                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:118)
                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1026)
                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1083)
                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:192)
                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                      at com.nononsenseapps.filepicker.AbstractFilePickerFragment.inflateRootView(AbstractFilePickerFragment.java:239)
                                                      at com.nononsenseapps.filepicker.AbstractFilePickerFragment.onCreateView(AbstractFilePickerFragment.java:165)
                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239)
                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1332)
                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
com.pdfviewer.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:554)
                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1249)
                                                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6701)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496)
                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

I searched and found that it's related to the theme of the file-picker but also i didn't find anything wrong in the theme:

```
<style name="FilePickerTheme" parent="NNF_BaseTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- Setting a divider is entirely optional -->
    <item name="nnf_list_item_divider">?android:attr/listDivider</item>

    <!-- Need to set this also to style create folder dialog -->
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/FilePickerAlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="FilePickerAlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

colorss.xml:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3f51b5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303f9f</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#5495fd</color>
```

Comment: The actual error `UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5:`

Comment: Thanks for the reply  but the error was truly related to the theme I used, which wasn't the FilePickerTheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually related to the theme I am applying to the parent activity of this fragment `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` was causing the app to crash because the layout wasn't finding it's appropriate attributes and debugging xml is kinda tricky.

The ImageButton in the resources:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/nnf_button_ok_newfile"
            // this style line is the cause
            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:hint="@android:string/ok"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nnf_ic_save_black_24dp"
            android:tint="?attr/nnf_save_icon_color"/>
```

and the solution to this problem was to either change your Activity theme in the manifest to `android:theme="@style/FilePickerTheme"` which is bad for user experience to user different themes between activities, or the other solution which is to Override the `onCreate` method and set the theme before the creation of the activity happens as follows:
FilteredFilePickerFragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().setTheme(R.style.FilePickerTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```